# Tessellate the plane with arbitrary surfaces

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

It is known that every surface can be represented by a polygon and glueing the sides appropriately ([A source](https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/math431/Surfaces.pdf)). It is also known that the only tessellations of the plane are by squares, triangles and hexagons. It is for example possible to "tessellate" the plane by the torus [image: From Jeff Weeks' Torus Games]
or by the Klein bottle [image: Also from Jeff Weeks' Torus Games]. But is it possible for an arbitrary surface? My guess would be that it is not.

EDIT: I have since found the chapter "Plane tessellation representations of compact surfaces" in "Surface Topology", which explains why it is possible to "tessellate" the *hyperbolic* plane with the fundamental polygon of surfaces.

Comment: The torus tessellation on the Möbius strip would not work, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible for any surface, and the only surfaces you can do this are the torus and the Klein bottle.

So suppose $P$ is some polygon in the plane such that with some gluing data of its edges we obtain a tessellation of the plane, and considering the quotient space we get a surface $S$.

Say the vertices of $P$ are identified to $v$ points of the quotient space $S$. Each edge of $P$ is glued to only one other edge; as $S$ is a closed manifold. Thus $P$ has an even number $2n$ of edges, which become $n$ arcs in the quotient $S$.

Recall that for any surface $X$ obtained by gluing $p$ disjoint polygons of the plane along their edges, the Euler characteristic $\chi(X)$ of $X$ equals

$$ p-n+v$$

where $2n$ is the number of edges of the polygons; this number is even because the same reason given above, and $v$ is the number of points of $X$ coming from a vertex of one of the polygons. The fact that $\chi(X)$ does not depend on this particular description of the surface $X$ using polygons is proved using the homology groups of $X$, a proof of this can be found for instance in Bredon's book *Topology and Geometry*.

So for our surface  $S$ we get its Euler characteristic is $1-n+v$. Now as with $P$ and this gluing data we get a tessellation of the plane, if $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ is the equivalence class of a vertex of $P$ in the quotient; of course the $v_i$'s are vertices of $P$, then we must have
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\theta_i=2\pi,$$

where $\theta_i$ is the angle of $P$ at the vertex $v_i$, hence the sum of the internal angles of $P$ must sum up to $2\pi v.$

However as $P$ has $2n$ sides, the sum of its interior angles must be $(2n-2)\pi$, in consequence
$$2\pi\chi(S)=2\pi(1-n+v)=\pi(2-2n)+2\pi v=0.$$

Therefore the Euler characteristic of $S$ must be $0$, and thus $S$ can only be either the torus or the Klein bottle.

The equality $2\pi\chi(S)=0$ we obtained is actually a very particular case of the [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem).